# How to check email input from HTML button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The outcome I want:

1. Click the button (div class button)
2. Check what is inputted (div class email)
3. If it isn't an email, return an error that it isn't an email.

```
<div class="Email">
<input type="text" name="" class="em" placeholder="Email Address">
</div>
<div class="button" > <h2 class="re"> Request Access </h2> </div>
</div>
```

I don't know where to start from JavaScript code. Any tips will help.

Comment: You could simply change `type="text"` to `type="email"` and let the browser do the validation for you. See [<input type="email">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email)

Comment: It's important to understand that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. You should always make a reasonable faith effort to solve your problem and include your code and results when you ask for help.

Comment: I would recommend having a look at [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) in JavaScript.

Comment: Regarding your HTML, you should probably use CSS to style the button text instead of an `<h2>` element. Otherwise, accessibility tools like screen readers might try to present the button as a text heading, which I assume is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to validate things like emails, passwords, usernames, etc. It's really powerful and can do a ton.

**Solution:**

```html
<form class="email">
    <input type="email" class="emailInput" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <button type="submit">Request Access</button>
    <p id="error" style="color: red; display: none">Please enter a valid email</p>
</form>

<script>
    const email = document.querySelector('.emailInput');
    const submit = document.querySelector('button');
    const error = document.querySelector('#error');

    const showError = () => {
        error.style.display = 'block';
    };

    submit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!email.value.match(/[^@ \t\r\n]+@[^@ \t\r\n]+\.[^@ \t\r\n]+/)) {
            return showError();
        }

        console.log('success');
    });
</script>
```